# Why not run apt update automatically with apt install?

Tags: apt

So in a lot of tutorials, you can see a suggestion to

```
apt update
```

which of course makes a lot of sense, and only then

```
apt install whatever
```

Why not run apt update automatically with apt install? This saves time, and just more convenient, and I believe this is the default behavior of MacOS

```
brew install
```

Comment: some people pay for their bandwidth usage.

Comment: So by running this command manually before installing a package, bandwidth will not be affected?

Comment: Of course it will, but if they have other reasons to run an update (like wanting to know if updates to something already installed is available), an update might have been run so short ago that having it done automatically again is pointless and just wastes bandwidth.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Henrik said, `apt update` and `apt install` perform two different operations. Even if you always use `apt` the same way (first `update`, then `install`), that's not the case for every single person in the world.

Calling `update` silently before each `install` operation is a bad idea in the following scenarios:

1. If someone needs to install packages one by one (maybe fetching the exit code of `apt` for further processing), `apt` would waste bandwidth.
2. You don't need an internet connection to use `install` if the packages were previously downloaded, so doing an `update` is pointless.
3. When using `install` it's possible to append a hyphen `-` to package's name to remove it if it's installed, so doing an `update` is pointless.

But, if you really want `apt` to behave as you want, you could:

1. Add a function like this to your `.rc` file: `apt-install() { apt update && apt install "${@}"; }`.
2. Propose your suggestion to `apt`/your distro maintainers.
3. Modify the source code of `apt`. It's free software after all.

Answer (score 3):

## Rationale

Your thinking is alright, except if:

```
apt-get install package
```

called silently before each installation:

```
apt-get update
```

That would make those updates redundant if you install more than one package.

Plus, it would significantly prolong the time for each package installation.

And it is not even feasible, because the one package could be dependent on another.

---

## Conclusion

You need to call:

```
apt-get update
```

before any installation of packages and / or upgrade.

Comment: That would make those updates redundant if you install more than one package. - but why? I don't understand this, you mean update will run before each of the pacage, if the command like this would be run?
`apt install pac1 pac2 pac3`
This is easily fixable.

If the conclusion is just to always run it manually every time, I honestly don't get why it should not be automated.

Comment: I agree that doing an `update` before each individual package is installed is silly and problematic, but this doesn't really address the idea of doing an update *once* before the requested set of installations.

Answer (score 2):

It's two very distinct operations, and it's not hard to imagine use cases for running `update` without `install`, so just for that reason they should be separate.

And you need an updated list of packages and dependencies before you can meaningfully decide what to install. Imagine you want to install something that depends on a fooserver, if you just use the lists you have you might not consider the fancy new fooserver that someone uploaded to the repositories a few minutes ago, that really suits your needs better.

Comment: Well I'm not suggesting to deprecate `update` it can stay just fine, I only suggest to call it silently every time `install` is called.
As for the new packages available, there is an `apt-cache search` and google, to help out with this.

Comment: `apt-cache search` only uses the locally available information, and searching the net (google are evil, don't use them) seems more complicated than just reading the package descriptions with `apt show <package>` (I think that functionality used to be in `apt-cache` if you don't have a new enough `apt`).